# Correlation items like amazon.com

Tags: sql-server

we are in retail company and they need correlation items that have related together 
in sales may sales id have full combination or have more than them

```
1. a    b       1200
2. a    c       1700
3. a    b   c   1200
```

i was tring

```
select [itemids],count(*)from (
SELECT 
   S.Salesid ,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + S1.itemid 
          FROM banta_sales_ts S1
          WHERE  S.Salesid =  S1.Salesid
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [itemids]
FROM banta_sales_ts S
GROUP BY S.Salesid) as grp group by [itemids]
```

but that related salesid i need full correlation items

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. It's typically expected that you include some code in your question, tell us what you've tried, be specific where you got stuck, etc. Note that you can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Please mention which database and which platform you are using in tags...